# Can I give Website audit tool on my website?

Tags: php, seo, web-crawler

I'm planning to develop an online website audit tool using PHP and CURL like one on [Woorank](http://www.woorank.com/)  and want to make it available on my website so that people can check website audit report for multiple sites completely Free. In development of this tool, I need to crawl some sites like Alexa. I want to know is it permitted? If yes with rules, please let me know. Appreciate any kind of suggestions related to my concern.

Comment: You need to ask `Alexa` or check if they already have an API for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crawling websites is allowed. However, breaking websites is not in most countries. This means you should not interfere with the website. Just observe. By convention, you should also follow  the [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) guidelines.

The specific laws differ per country. Keep in mind though that you cannot show the actual site you crawled because they owners have copyright. However, you can (in most countries) distribute the results of your audit.

Comment: Thank you Alex. I'll follow the robots.txt guidelines. I'll search for more details.

Answer (score 1):

**You can follow these steps to begin with:**

1. Register for Amazon Web Services (AWS).
2. Register for Alexa Web Information Service.
3. Read how to submit requests to this service on:

   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AlexaWebInfoService/latest/.

Of course, for steps 1 and 2, you will have to pay...

Comment: Thank you barak manos. I'll check with the details you've shared.

Answer (score 0):

you can use siteliner.com to help to develope the website aduit tool. siteliner is a website to offering website report such as duplicate content internal page, brokern link and many more. you can also see the smallseotools.com. site aduti tools.